# Grails oAuth2 Provider plugin does not authenticate for grant_type 'password'

Tags: grails, spring-security, oauth-2.0, grails-plugin, spring-security-oauth2

I have an ios app which communicates with a REST API developed on Grails. In order to secure the REST API, I decided to use oAuth 2.0 'Resource Owner Password' flow. For the grails app to act as an oAuth 2.0 provider I am using the following http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth2-provider
For Client with id as 'client' ,secret as '1234' and User with username as 'user' and password as 'password',the request for token is as follows

```
POST /oauth2-test/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.113:8080
Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50OjEyMzQ=
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&scope=read&username=user&password=password
```

The response received is

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this  resource"
}
```

My config.groovy edits for Spring Security and oAuth 2.0 provider plugin looks like this

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'test.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'test.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'test.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll'],
    '/oauth/authorize.dispatch': ["isFullyAuthenticated() and (request.getMethod().equals('GET') or request.getMethod().equals('POST'))"],
    '/oauth/token.dispatch'    : ["isFullyAuthenticated() and request.getMethod().equals('POST')"]
]

// Added by the Spring Security OAuth2 Provider plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.clientLookup.className = 'test.Client'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.authorizationCodeLookup.className = 'test.AuthorizationCode'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.accessTokenLookup.className = 'test.AccessToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.refreshTokenLookup.className = 'test.RefreshToken'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = [
        'clientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider',
        'daoAuthenticationProvider',
        'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
        'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider'
]
grails.exceptionresolver.params.exclude = ['password', 'client_secret']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        '/oauth/token': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',
        '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',
        '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter'
]
```

- What am i doing wrong? I understand oAuth 2.0 is primarily for
  authorization and not authentication. So do I have to explicitly add
  a filter for authentication?I started with Grails without any
  experience on Springs and any help is appreciated as to how to do it?
- Does grant_type 'password' require client authentication? For grant
  type 'password' should user authentication not suffice?Even if it
  needs to authenticate the client it would use Basic Authentication
  according to my understanding. So do I need to explicitly add a basic
  authentication filter?

Comment: Are you passing client_id and client_secret in the Authorization header?  Did you try passing them in the request instead?

Comment: Yes I am passing the client_id and client_secret in the Authorization header. Yes, tried passing them in the request as x-www-form-urlencoded and got the same result.. No change.

Comment: How did you resolve this please?

Comment: There's a discussion on Github on how to support HTTP Basic Authentication properly in the Spring Security OAuth2 Provider plugin: https://github.com/bluesliverx/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/issues/65

Answer (score 2):

Basic Authentication is not enabled by default in Spring Security Core, so you can't put your `client_id` and `client_secret` in the Authorization header; in this case just add them to the request parameters (like `grant_type`)

The following CURL example should work:

```
curl -v -X POST \
-d "grant_type=password" \
-d "client_id=client" \
-d "client_secret=1234" \
-d "scope=read" \
-d "username=user" \
-d "password=password" http://localhost:8080/oauth2-test/oauth/token

{"access_token":"d3eb1c1c-9922-4cfc-87e3-7efca9a8a2f2","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"e790efc2-e708-4391-9a7b-e4d86dc70816","expires_in":42545,"scope":"read"}
```

Note that OAuth2 requires HTTPS. If you're running Grails with the `-https` option (`grails run-app -https`), the command is this:

```
curl -v --insecure -X POST \
-d "grant_type=password" \
-d "client_id=client" \
-d "client_secret=1234" \
-d "scope=read" \
-d "username=user" \
-d "password=password" https://localhost:8443/oauth2-test/oauth/token
```

When I omit the request parameter `client_id`, I get the following reply:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
```

**Update**

If you want to be able to use HTTP Basic Authentication for the client_id, just enabling Basic Authentication in Spring Security Core (in Config.groovy) is not the solution since the BasicAuthenticationFilter is not initialised in a way suitable for oauth2. When the credentials are correct or omitted everything works as expected, but when the credentials are provided but wrong, you'll get a HTML response.

There is currently an issue on the project's Github page where the proper way of handling Basic Authentication is discussed:

https://github.com/bluesliverx/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/issues/65

Comment: I have a different issue with password grant type I got the access token successfully but when I try to access any resource with this access token I get Bearer error="Invalid token" can you help me with that please?